# I wanted to test if an user input is vowel or not. But the program showing the else output every time

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, html

```
<p>Please insert a letter: <br/> 
        <input id="demo" type="text" name="letter" placeholder="Insert a letter">
        <button type="button" onclick="test()">Check it</button> <br>
        <span id="res"></span>
    </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
let vowel = document.getElementById('demo').value;

function test() {
    if (vowel === 'a' || vowel === 'e' || vowel === 'i' || vowel === 'o' || vowel === 'u') {
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 'This is a vowel !'; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 'This is a consonant !'; 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're defining `vowel` only once, outside of `test`, so it doesn't update, and it'll always be equal to `""`. I also refactored your `if` statement using [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
function test() {
  let vowel = document.getElementById('demo').value;
  if ("aeiou".includes(vowel)) {
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 'This is a vowel !';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 'This is a consonant !';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Please insert a letter: <br/>
  <input id="demo" type="text" name="letter" placeholder="Insert a letter">
  <button type="button" onclick="test()">Check it</button> <br>
  <span id="res"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `vowel` variable is being set outside the scope of the test function, so it isn't being updated when the button is clicked. You need to move it inside the scope like so:

```
function test() {
    let vowel = document.getElementById('demo').value;

    if (vowel === 'a' || vowel === 'e' || vowel === 'i' || vowel === 'o' || vowel === 'u') {
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 'This is a vowel !'; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 'This is a consonant !'; 
    }
}
```